# Animation in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, animation

I would like make an animation in GeoServer using three shapefile.
I looked this page https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/time.html#specifying-a-list-of-times but I didn't understand how I can create a "time specification".
How can I do this?

Comment: What specifically don't you understand? Please also provide more details on the data you are trying to animate. Are the times instances or ranges? Are all the features in your shapefiles representative of a single instance/range or multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time series in GeoServer tend to be collections of rasters or single vector files.

So you need a single shapefile with a date column in it, the animation will then allow you to show the various features in the layer that match the time settings.